# Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series fix? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hardware-failure

My laptop is an Inspiron 15 5000 series with a touchscreen input. It has a quad-core AMD 8 processor and AMD Radeon R5 dedicated graphics.

Today, I caught it falling off a low table, but it bumped the ground with the LAN port (with a cable inserted). I noticed that wired networks no longer worked. Upon further inspection I saw that the metal inside the port was a little bent. After bending it back the port still doesn't work.

Is there some fix I can try at home, or should I send it to Dell or a repair shop?

Comment: Wait for some other answer, but I suspect you have broken some contact inside... I hope for you the contrary. Check if the system reports some non working device...

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the fall caused some sort of damage to the LAN port. If you are tech-savy and feel confident enough you can open up the case and see if there is an easy fix, e.g. a loose connector. Without opening it, nobody can tell for sure if it is permanent damage or not (apart from checking the device manager, as the comment suggested).